# Is changing variables the same as substitutions?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have asked several on a **similar matter.** This time the question is tad different.

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-x^2} dx$$

We let $x=y \implies dx=dy$

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-(x^2 + y^2)} dxdy$$

But then how do we conclude that:

$$x^2 + y^2 = r^2$$

Since $x^2 + y^2 = 2x^2$??

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you mean $e^{-2x^2}$ in your first integral?

Comment: What do you think $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-(x^2 + y^2)} dxdy$$ means? A double integral is over two variables, not a line. I think you are misunderstanding the standard solution for this integral, which does not involve setting $x=y$.

Comment: How do you go from one variable to two with a substitution? The answer to this integral is $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$ by the way, it is a multiple of the error function.

Comment: You have asked a lot of similar questions. What course are you taking? There seem to be some serious problems understanding variables in integrals, and even though people explain, new ones appear. Maybe that should be discussed in detail with your teacher?

Comment: Dont have a teacher.

Comment: A question: Does the value under a curve changes, if i relable the horizontal axis from "apples" to "oranges"?

Comment: @tired, it doesnt but can you prove it?

Comment: Are you looking for a proof of why substitution works?

Answer (score 4):

**First Problem**

While it is true that using the substitution $x\mapsto y$, we get
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-y^2}\,\mathrm{d}y\tag{1}
$$
$(1)$ is not equal to
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-y^2}\,\mathrm{d}y\tag{2}
$$
Furthermore, neither $x$ nor $y$ are dependent on the other in either $(1)$ or $(2)$. In $(1)$, we have simply renamed a dummy variable. This is the same as substituting $x\mapsto y$ to go from
$$
f(x)=x^2+2\tag{3}
$$
to
$$
f(y)=y^2+2\tag{4}
$$

---

**Second Problem**

To convert the integral
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\tag{5}
$$
to polar coordinates, we have $r^2=x^2+y^2$ and $\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y=r\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}r$ where we've used the Jacobian of the change of variables
$$
\begin{align}
x&=r\cos(\theta)\\
y&=r\sin(\theta)
\end{align}\tag{6}
$$
That is,
$$
\begin{align}
\det\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(r,\theta)}
&=\det\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial r}&\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial r}\\\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}&\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\det\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\theta)&\sin(\theta)\\-r\sin(\theta)&r\cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}\\[12pt]
&=r\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $(5)$ becomes
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-r^2}\,r\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}r
&=2\pi\int_0^\infty e^{-r^2}\,r\,\mathrm{d}r\\
&=\pi\int_0^\infty e^{-s}\,\mathrm{d}s\\
&=\pi\tag{8}
\end{align}
$$
where we have used another substitution: $s\mapsto r^2$.

Using $(1)$, $(2)$, $(5)$, and $(8)$, we get
$$
\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^2=\pi\tag{9}
$$